# SSRS multi-value parameter showing value instead of label

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with many paremeters to filter the data presented in the report. One of the parameters is MainContact. This is a multi-value parameter. The values and labels are taken from a query. The values are BIGINT referring to an Id for a Contact and the labels NVARCHAR contact names.

When I deploy the report to Report Manager the labels show up correctly in the drop-down list.

I have a linked report (NOT a drill through report) to this original report in which some of the parameters are either hidden or given different defaults. The problem I have found is that as soon as I make changes to these other parameter settings in the linked report the MainContact parameter drop-down list changes to show the BIGINT parameter values instead of the labels. The original report is unaffected, and continues to show the contact name.

I have tried CASTing the BIGINT values as NVARCHAR(20) in my dataset but this makes no difference.

Any idea how to resolve this problem as the values are meaningless to the report's users?

I am using:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated) Version 11.0.61030.0 Q11REL
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012   04932-004-0017006-02018
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 11.0.3402.0
and deploying reports to a SQL Server 2012 version 11.0.3000